# Angular 2 error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I know this question is asked about 100 times but i am getting this error. Please check the screenshot.

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>             at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/date-formatter.js:2:14)
>             at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/date-formatter.js:13:4)
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/moment
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/date-formatter.js
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/datepicker-inner.js
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/datepicker.js
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/datepicker-popup.js
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker.js
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js
>         Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

I followed the solution which is given for fixing system config

```
System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          'ng2-bootstrap': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },
        map: {
          // place for ng2 modules mapping
          'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
        }
});
```

but after this solution I am getting the error and the page is not loading...

anyone know the steps to follow then please let me know.

Comment: `I know this question is asked about 100 times` ....

Comment: Please post your code for datepickerformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, ng2-boostrap provided a bundled file. Simply add it into a script element and remove the related configuration of SystemJS:

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.js"></script>

System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-bootstrap': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      // place for ng2 modules mapping
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
    }
});
```

This can be done after installing ng2-bootstrap with npm.